# Singularity Grid Columns Alignment

Tags: singularitygs

Why HTML elements don't properly align to grid columns.
[https://pbs.twimg.com/media/BqaoDBzCMAEzcTG.jpg:large](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/BqaoDBzCMAEzcTG.jpg%3alarge)

Comment: Please consider upvoting and selecting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

> **IT IS IMPORTANT TO NOTE** that CSS Gradients are not 100% reliable visualizations of your grid, so do not be concerned if your items do not line up to the visualization. If they are off by a little bit, assume that they are aligned correctly and your visualization is off. Webkit browsers, and especially Google Chrome, seem to be the worst with the gradients, whereas Firefox seems to be the best.

Source: https://github.com/Team-Sass/Singularity/wiki/Creating-Grids#grid-backgrounds-may-be-inaccurate

Also, read this: http://www.palantir.net/blog/responsive-design-s-dirty-little-secret

And Singularity author's reply: http://snugug.com/musings/on-responsive-designs-dirty-little-secret